# studying parallel programming python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from source.RUN import*

def func(r,grid,pos,h):
    return r,grid,pos,h
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()  # Creates a pool with as many workers as you have CPU cores
    results = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in  pos[-1]<2:
    results.append(Pool.apply_async(LISTE,(r,grid,pos[i,:],h)))
    p.close()
    p.join()

for result in results:
    print('liste', result.get())
```

I want to create Pool for `(LISTE,(r,grid,pos[i,:],h))` process and `i` is in pos which is variable in different file which is a `ndarray[]` and I have to call this whole function in another file in between one While Loop. but this code gives error and if I am using 
`if __name__ == '__main__':`
it will not pass through below the `if __name__ == '__main__':` module
please give me idea how I can make it

Comment: This: `for i in  pos[-1]<2:` doesn't make sense. What do you actually mean there?

Comment: for i in  pos[-1]<2: in pos[-1]<2: is a ndarray ...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... isn't `pos[-1]<2` just going to evaluate to `True` or `False`? So then you're doing `for i in True:` or `for i in False:`.

Comment: no pos[-1]<2: has some value in array.. not Boolean..can I have your email I can send you something

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a somewhat difficult time understanding your question. But I think this is what you're looking for:

You want to be able to call a function that creates a pool given `r, grid, pos, h` Iterate over `pos` feed it to the `Pool`, then return the results. You also want to be able to access that function from different modules. If that's what you're asking, you can do it like this:

**async_module.py**:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Not sure where the LISTE function gets defined, but it needs to be in here.

def do_LISTE(*args):
    # args is a tuple containing (r, grid, pos[i, :], h)
    # we use tuple expansion (*args( to send each parameter to LISTE
    return LISTE(*args)

def async_process(r,grid,pos,h):
    return r,grid,pos,h
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()  # Creates a pool with as many workers as you have CPU cores
    results = p.map(do_LISTE, [(r,grid,pos[i,:], h) for i in pos[-1]<2])
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return results
```

Then in some other module:

```
from async_module import async_process

def do_async_processing():
    r = "something"
    grid = get_grid()
    pos = get_pos()
    h = 345
    results = async_process(r, grid, pos, h)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_async_processing()  # Make sure the entry point is protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`.
```

Comment: thanks dano for your answer..still not get satisfactory result .can I have your email id so I can send you whole code for better idea..or dhruvalraval@ymail.com just ping me on this id..